# Maintaining the scroll position of multi select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My client does not want control key to used to select/unselect items in multi-select list. I have come up with a solution but can't seem to keep the scroll position of the selected item in Chrome. This seems to be working fine in Firefox. What's wrong here? Or if there is any better solution, please suggest.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.multi-select option').on('mousedown',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var select = $(this).parent();
        var selectTop = select.scrollTop();
                
        $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
        select.scrollTop(selectTop);

        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="Title" class="multi-select" style="width: 143px; height: 250px; overflow: scroll;" multiple="multiple">
        <option  value="1">1 </option>
        <option  value="2">2 </option>
        <option  value="3">3</option>
        <option  value="4">4</option>
        <option  value="5">5</option>
        <option  value="6">6</option>
        <option  value="7">7</option>
        <option  value="8">8</option>
        <option  value="9">9</option>
        <option  value="10">10</option>
        <option  value="11">11</option>
        <option  value="12">12</option>
        <option  value="13">13</option>
        <option  value="14">14</option>
        <option  value="15">15</option>
        <option  value="16">16</option>
        <option  value="17">17</option>
        <option  value="18">18</option>
        <option  value="19">19</option>
        <option  value="20">20</option>
        <option  value="21">21</option>
        <option  value="22">22</option>
        <option  value="23">23</option>
        <option  value="24">24</option>
        <option  value="25">25</option>
        <option  value="26">26</option>
        <option  value="27">27</option>
        <option  value="28">28</option>
        <option  value="31">31</option></select>
```

Comment: Might sound like a silly solution but.. why not use checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectTop;
    var mustChangeScrollTop = false;

    $('.multi-select').on('scroll',function (e) {
        if (mustChangeScrollTop){
            $(this).scrollTop(selectTop);
             mustChangeScrollTop = false;
        }
        return true;
    });
 
    $('.multi-select option').on('mousedown',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        selectTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop(); 
        $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);  
        mustChangeScrollTop = true;

        return false;
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="Title" class="multi-select" style="width: 143px; height: 250px; overflow: scroll;" multiple="multiple">
        <option  value="1">1 </option>
        <option  value="2">2 </option>
        <option  value="3">3</option>
        <option  value="4">4</option>
        <option  value="5">5</option>
        <option  value="6">6</option>
        <option  value="7">7</option>
        <option  value="8">8</option>
        <option  value="9">9</option>
        <option  value="10">10</option>
        <option  value="11">11</option>
        <option  value="12">12</option>
        <option  value="13">13</option>
        <option  value="14">14</option>
        <option  value="15">15</option>
        <option  value="16">16</option>
        <option  value="17">17</option>
        <option  value="18">18</option>
        <option  value="19">19</option>
        <option  value="20">20</option>
        <option  value="21">21</option>
        <option  value="22">22</option>
        <option  value="23">23</option>
        <option  value="24">24</option>
        <option  value="25">25</option>
        <option  value="26">26</option>
        <option  value="27">27</option>
        <option  value="28">28</option>
        <option  value="31">31</option></select>
```

**Explanation**

I noticed that in Chrome there is an unnecessary scroll after the return from the mousedown event. So a solution/workaround is to add an onscroll event and reset (`$(this).scrollTop(selectTop);`) the top of the select area (`selectTop`) to what it was before the change of the selected option (`selectTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop();`). The `mustChangeScrollTop` variable is needed because the onscroll event is not called only when the unnessary scroll in Chrome occurs, but also when the user scrolls by hand. So when the unnecessary scroll is about to happen (which is when the user selects an option) we set the `mustChangeScrollTop` to true and then (when the unnecessary scroll occurs) we understand it by checking that it is true and then we set it back to false, so that it won't bother the user's scroll.

I tested it in Chrome and it works fine. I hope this helped you.